Combine two Interleave Slowly Changing Dimension Tables (SCD) Type 2 in Oracle SQL
Data Structure
I have two tables in Oracle SQL: dt_cust (customer data) and dt_adre (address data). Both tables use a Slowly Changing Dimension (SCD) Type 2 design to track historical changes.
Table Columns:



Column
Description




ID
Customer ID (primary key in both tables)


*_FROM
Start date of the state


*_TO
End date of the state (3000-01-01 = indefinite)


*_CREATED
Date the state was created


*_REPLACED
Date the state was replaced (3000-01-01 = not replaced)


VAL1
Customer attribute (in dt_cust)


VAL2
Address attribute (in dt_adre)



dt_cust



ID
CUST_FROM
CUST_TO
CUST_CREATED
CUST_REPLACED
VAL1




1
01-JAN-22
01-JAN-3000
05-JAN-22
05-FEB-22
NULL


1
01-JAN-22
01-JAN-3000
05-FEB-22
05-MAR-22
1


1
01-JAN-22
31-JAN-22
05-MAR-22
01-JAN-3000
1


1
01-FEB-22
01-JAN-3000
05-MAR-22
01-JAN-3000
2


2
01-MAY-23
01-JAN-3000
05-MAY-23
01-JAN-3000
33



dt_adre



ID
ADRE_FROM
ADRE_TO
ADRE_CREATED
ADRE_REPLACED
VAL2




1
01-JAN-22
01-JAN-3000
05-JAN-22
15-JAN-22
A


1
01-JAN-22
01-JAN-3000
15-JAN-22
15-FEB-22
B


1
01-JAN-22
10-FEB-22
15-FEB-22
01-JAN-3000
B


1
11-FEB-22
01-JAN-3000
15-FEB-22
01-JAN-3000
C


2
01-MAY-23
01-JAN-3000
05-MAY-23
07-MAY-23
X


2
01-MAY-23
01-JAN-3000
07-MAY-23
01-JAN-3000
Y



dt_result



ID
FROM
TO
CREATED
REPLACED
VAL1
VAL2




1
01-JAN-22
01-JAN-3000
05-JAN-22
15-JAN-22
NULL
A


1
01-JAN-22
01-JAN-3000
15-JAN-22
05-FEB-22
NULL
B


1
01-JAN-22
01-JAN-3000
05-FEB-22
15-FEB-22
1
B


1
01-JAN-22
10-FEB-22
15-FEB-22
05-MAR-22
1
B


1
11-FEB-22
01-JAN-3000
15-FEB-22
05-MAR-22
1
C


1
01-JAN-22
31-JAN-22
05-MAR-22
01-JAN-3000
1
B


1
01-FEB-22
10-FEB-22
05-MAR-22
01-JAN-3000
2
B


1
11-FEB-22
01-JAN-3000
05-MAR-22
01-JAN-3000
2
C


2
01-MAY-23
01-JAN-3000
05-MAY-23
07-MAY-23
33
X


2
01-MAY-23
01-JAN-3000
07-MAY-23
01-JAN-3000
33
Y



DESCRIPTION
My data has the following design: whenever a new ID is created, it has personal data in dt_cust and address data in dt_adre.

FROM/TO: each state has a valid time period, from when until when this state is valid. TO = "01-01-3000" indicates it is valid until forever.
CREATED: this date shows when the state has been created. This can be prior, on, or after the validity period. Here it means, the customer 1 was created on the 5th of January with being a customer since 1st of January.
REPLACED: When a state loses its validity because it gets overwritten, REPLACED is filled on the old state with CREATED from the new state. REPLACED = "01-01-3000" indicates it is not replaced (yet). The REPLACED = "01-01-3000" are all states that are currently in effect.

Example
Looking at data dt_cust, its current rows were created sequentially:

The customer was created on 5th of January. From then on, it was a customer in our system with being a customer since January 1st. VAL1 was initially missing:




ID
CUST_FROM
CUST_TO
CUST_CREATED
CUST_REPLACED
VAL1




1
01-01-2022
01-01-3000
05-01-2022
01-01-3000
NA




On the 5th of February, the missing VAL1 got filled. So the old State was completely invalidated. Now row two is the only State in effect (REPLACED = "01-01-3000"):




ID
CUST_FROM
CUST_TO
CUST_CREATED
CUST_REPLACED
VAL1




1
01-01-2022
01-01-3000
05-01-2022
05-02-2022
NA


1
01-01-2022
01-01-3000
05-02-2022
01-01-3000
1




On the 5th of March, VAL1 was changed from 1 to 2 but only starting from 1st of February. Until 31st of January, it's still 1, and only afterward, it's 2. So, row 2 gets invalidated by setting REPLACED and the table now has two states in effect (REPLACED = "01-01-3000"), State One from 1.1. until 31.1. and 1.2. until forever.




ID
CUST_FROM
CUST_TO
CUST_CREATED
CUST_REPLACED
VAL1




1
01-01-2022
01-01-3000
05-01-2022
05-02-2022
NA


1
01-01-2022
01-01-3000
05-02-2022
05-03-2022
1


1
01-01-2022
31-01-2022
05-03-2022
01-01-3000
1


1
01-02-2022
01-01-3000
05-03-2022
01-01-3000
2



As you see, the history of the states is not deleted but preserved by setting REPLACED and creating new entries.
TASK
Both tables are structured that way, but they are not interconnected. Only if something in the table itself changes, new rows are created, not if the other table gets updated. I want to create a combined table that combines the history of both tables.
Result Explanation for Customer 1:



ID
FROM
TO
CREATED
REPLACED
VAL1
VAL2
Explanation




1
2022-01-01
3000-01-01
2022-01-05
2022-01-15
NA
A
Initial entry with missing VAL1 and initial VAL2


1
2022-01-01
3000-01-01
2022-01-15
2022-02-05
NA
B
On 15.01, it is corrected that VAL2 should have been 'B'


1
2022-01-01
3000-01-01
2022-02-05
2022-02-15
1
B
On 05.02, VAL1 is filled from the start


1
2022-01-01
2022-02-10
2022-02-15
2022-03-05
1
B
On 15.02, Customer moves from 'B' to 'C', so it needs a break on the 10th (until then, it's 'B')


1
2022-02-11
3000-01-01
2022-02-15
2022-03-05
1
C
...and from the 11th, it's 'C'


1
2022-01-01
2022-01-31
2022-03-05
3000-01-01
1
B
On 05.03, VAL1 is changed from 1 to 2, starting from Feb 1st (until 31.01, it's 'B')


1
2022-02-01
2022-02-10
2022-03-05
3000-01-01
2
B
VAL1 changes, but VAL2 is still 'B' from 01.02 until 10.02


1
2022-02-11
3000-01-01
2022-03-05
3000-01-01
2
C
The last row reflects the change in VAL2 from 'B' to 'C'



Example Data
-- Create the dt_cust table
CREATE TABLE dt_cust (
  ID            NUMBER,
  CUST_FROM     DATE,
  CUST_TO       DATE,
  CUST_CREATED  DATE,
  CUST_REPLACED DATE,
  VAL1        NUMBER
);

-- Insert data into dt_cust
INSERT INTO dt_cust VALUES (1, TO_DATE('01-01-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('01-01-3000', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('05-01-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('05-02-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), NULL);
INSERT INTO dt_cust VALUES (1, TO_DATE('01-01-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('01-01-3000', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('05-02-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('05-03-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 1);
INSERT INTO dt_cust VALUES (1, TO_DATE('01-01-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('31-01-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('05-03-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('01-01-3000', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 1);
INSERT INTO dt_cust VALUES (1, TO_DATE('01-02-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('01-01-3000', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('05-03-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('01-01-3000', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 2);
INSERT INTO dt_cust VALUES (2, TO_DATE('01-05-2023', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('01-01-3000', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('05-05-2023', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('01-01-3000', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 33);

-- Create the dt_adre table
CREATE TABLE dt_adre (
  ID            NUMBER,
  ADRE_FROM     DATE,
  ADRE_TO       DATE,
  ADRE_CREATED  DATE,
  ADRE_REPLACED DATE,
  VAL2        VARCHAR2(1)
);

-- Insert data into dt_adre
INSERT INTO dt_adre VALUES (1, TO_DATE('01-01-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('01-01-3000', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('05-01-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('15-01-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'A');
INSERT INTO dt_adre VALUES (1, TO_DATE('01-01-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('01-01-3000', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('15-01-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('15-02-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'B');
INSERT INTO dt_adre VALUES (1, TO_DATE('01-01-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('10-02-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('15-02-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('01-01-3000', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'B');
INSERT INTO dt_adre VALUES (1, TO_DATE('11-02-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('01-01-3000', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('15-02-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('01-01-3000', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'C');
INSERT INTO dt_adre VALUES (2, TO_DATE('01-05-2023', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('01-01-3000', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('05-05-2023', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('07-05-2023', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'X');
INSERT INTO dt_adre VALUES (2, TO_DATE('01-05-2023', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('01-01-3000', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('07-05-2023', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('01-01-3000', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'Y');


If you want to join the tables using the created/replaced range then you can use:
SELECT COALESCE(c.id, a.id) AS id,
       GREATEST(
         COALESCE(c.cust_from, a.adre_from),
         COALESCE(a.adre_from, c.cust_from)
       ) AS "FROM",
       LEAST(
         COALESCE(c.cust_to, a.adre_to),
         COALESCE(a.adre_to, c.cust_to)
       ) AS "TO",
       GREATEST(
         COALESCE(c.cust_created, a.adre_created),
         COALESCE(a.adre_created, c.cust_created)
       ) AS created,
       LEAST(
         COALESCE(c.cust_replaced, a.adre_replaced),
         COALESCE(a.adre_replaced, c.cust_replaced)
       ) AS replaced,
       c.val1,
       a.val2
FROM   dt_cust c
       FULL OUTER JOIN dt_adre a
       ON     c.id = a.id
          AND c.cust_created < a.adre_replaced
          AND a.adre_created < c.cust_replaced
WHERE  GREATEST(
         COALESCE(c.cust_from, a.adre_from),
         COALESCE(a.adre_from, c.cust_from)
       )
       <
       LEAST(
         COALESCE(c.cust_to, a.adre_to),
         COALESCE(a.adre_to, c.cust_to)
       )

Which, for the sample data, outputs:



ID
FROM
TO
CREATED
REPLACED
VAL1
VAL2




1
2022-01-01 00:00:00
3000-01-01 00:00:00
2022-01-05 00:00:00
2022-01-15 00:00:00
null
A


1
2022-01-01 00:00:00
3000-01-01 00:00:00
2022-01-15 00:00:00
2022-02-05 00:00:00
null
B


1
2022-01-01 00:00:00
3000-01-01 00:00:00
2022-02-05 00:00:00
2022-02-15 00:00:00
1
B


1
2022-01-01 00:00:00
2022-02-10 00:00:00
2022-02-15 00:00:00
2022-03-05 00:00:00
1
B


1
2022-01-01 00:00:00
2022-01-31 00:00:00
2022-03-05 00:00:00
3000-01-01 00:00:00
1
B


1
2022-02-01 00:00:00
2022-02-10 00:00:00
2022-03-05 00:00:00
3000-01-01 00:00:00
2
B


1
2022-02-11 00:00:00
3000-01-01 00:00:00
2022-02-15 00:00:00
2022-03-05 00:00:00
1
C


1
2022-02-11 00:00:00
3000-01-01 00:00:00
2022-03-05 00:00:00
3000-01-01 00:00:00
2
C


2
2023-05-01 00:00:00
3000-01-01 00:00:00
2023-05-05 00:00:00
2023-05-07 00:00:00
33
X


2
2023-05-01 00:00:00
3000-01-01 00:00:00
2023-05-07 00:00:00
3000-01-01 00:00:00
33
Y




If you want to join the tables using both the from/to and the created/replaced ranges then:
SELECT COALESCE(c.id, a.id) AS id,
       GREATEST(
         COALESCE(c.cust_from, a.adre_from),
         COALESCE(a.adre_from, c.cust_from)
       ) AS "FROM",
       LEAST(
         COALESCE(c.cust_to, a.adre_to),
         COALESCE(a.adre_to, c.cust_to)
       ) AS "TO",
       GREATEST(
         COALESCE(c.cust_created, a.adre_created),
         COALESCE(a.adre_created, c.cust_created)
       ) AS created,
       LEAST(
         COALESCE(c.cust_replaced, a.adre_replaced),
         COALESCE(a.adre_replaced, c.cust_replaced)
       ) AS replaced,
       c.val1,
       a.val2
FROM   dt_cust c
       FULL OUTER JOIN dt_adre a
       ON     c.id = a.id
          AND c.cust_from < a.adre_to
          AND a.adre_from < c.cust_to
          AND c.cust_created < a.adre_replaced
          AND a.adre_created < c.cust_replaced

Which outputs:



ID
FROM
TO
CREATED
REPLACED
VAL1
VAL2




1
2022-01-01 00:00:00
3000-01-01 00:00:00
2022-01-05 00:00:00
2022-01-15 00:00:00
null
A


1
2022-01-01 00:00:00
3000-01-01 00:00:00
2022-01-15 00:00:00
2022-02-05 00:00:00
null
B


1
2022-01-01 00:00:00
3000-01-01 00:00:00
2022-02-05 00:00:00
2022-02-15 00:00:00
1
B


1
2022-01-01 00:00:00
2022-02-10 00:00:00
2022-02-15 00:00:00
2022-03-05 00:00:00
1
B


1
2022-01-01 00:00:00
2022-01-31 00:00:00
2022-03-05 00:00:00
3000-01-01 00:00:00
1
B


1
2022-02-01 00:00:00
2022-02-10 00:00:00
2022-03-05 00:00:00
3000-01-01 00:00:00
2
B


1
2022-02-11 00:00:00
3000-01-01 00:00:00
2022-02-15 00:00:00
2022-03-05 00:00:00
1
C


1
2022-02-11 00:00:00
3000-01-01 00:00:00
2022-03-05 00:00:00
3000-01-01 00:00:00
2
C


2
2023-05-01 00:00:00
3000-01-01 00:00:00
2023-05-05 00:00:00
2023-05-07 00:00:00
33
X


2
2023-05-01 00:00:00
3000-01-01 00:00:00
2023-05-07 00:00:00
3000-01-01 00:00:00
33
Y



fiddle

Thank you! However, the first code does not produce the desired outcome. Row 8 should not exist and is even not valid since FROM (2022-02-11) comes after TO (2022-01-31).

@mnist To filter out those rows where from >= to, you can add a WHERE filter - I've updated the answer. You have not full explained your business logic so trying to implement a solution is challenging. Please edit your question and fully explain the logic of how you want to match the ranges from the two tables (does only the created/replaced ranges have to overlap, do both ranges have to overlap, etc.).
